# Deploy Flask app as single scripts in Apache

Tags: python, apache, deployment, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a website, mainly built with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. There are a few places where I'd like to use a python library, or just write in python, and then create specific functions with Flask.

Basically, I have functions in Python/Flask that return JSON, which I'd like to call from JavaScript. *How can I deploy Flask if I don't want my website to be an **entirely Flask-based** thing?* If I want to write one or two files here and there with Python/Flask but the rest in JavaScript, how do I deploy it? [What I've found online](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/) seems to be a solution to deploying Flask as a solution for the whole site, not just for a few individual scripts.

If it helps at all, I could have all my Flask apps in one directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using Flask to power an API that is consumed by a static site - the simplest way to do what you are looking to do is to simply mount your WSGI application at some sub-path that Flask will handle (for example `/api`) and then have your JavaScript / form submissions / etc. just point at the appropriate endpoints under `/api`.

In general, you can use the same server to serve both the static content and your WSGI application, but there's no *need* for them to be the same.  All of your static content might be served out of a CDN, with your API living on a single machine somewhere on AWS (for example).

Comment: This sounds good. If I run flask on port 80 *and* my other stuff at port 80, there won't be any conflicts as long as all my flask apps are `@app.route("/api/somepage")`? Do you have links to any tutorials that will help me execute this?

Comment: You actually will run whatever is *hosting* Flask on port 80 and have the hosting `httpd` (Apache, nginx, etc.) serve the static files.  [Here's an example for using Apache to serve the static files while having Flask + mod_wsgi handle the majority of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31299674/135978).  You would just change the mount point for mod_wsgi.